# Variable not required in a components Flutter

Tags: flutter, components

I'm having a problem with my component in flutter.

The code of my component:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller;
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Icon icon;

  const MyTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.obscureText,
    required this.icon,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
            ),
            fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            filled: true,
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
          suffixIcon: icon,
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I use an icon variable, but I would like to make that variable not necessarily to be used, but just in case I want to put an icon at the end of my TextField then I can do it.
The problem is that when I use my component in the Login Page if I write this it gives me an error:

```
MyTextField(controller: emailController, hintText: 'Email', obscureText: false, icon: null),
```

How can I fix?
Thanks in advance

Comment: just a simple "?" sign will do & rest are fine . just do this, final Icon? icon;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are indicating that the icon should be required , it should just change to that it can be null.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller;
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Icon? icon;

  const MyTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.obscureText,
      this.icon,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
            ),
            fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            filled: true,
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
          suffixIcon: icon,
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MyTextField(controller: emailController, hintText: 'Email', obscureText: false),